# How do you see the entire command history in interactive Python?

Tags: python, macos

I'm working on the default python interpreter on Mac OS X, and I <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> (cleared) my earlier commands. I can go through them one by one using the arrow keys. But is there an option like the --history option in bash shell, which shows you all the commands you've entered so far?

Comment: The `history` shell command is a program like any other. It isn't an "option" in `bash` command.

Comment: To be precise: `history` is a shell builtin.

Comment: For [iPython](http://ipython.org/) the answer is `%history`. And the `-g` option gets [earlier sessions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32019203/673991).

Comment: %history -g + %edit works best

Comment: Just asked the [equivalent question for Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62802667/print-python-history-from-interactive-prompt-on-windows)

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Use [`readline.get_current_history_length()`](http://docs.python.org/library/readline.html#readline.get_current_history_length) to get the length, and [`readline.get_history_item()`](http://docs.python.org/library/readline.html#readline.get_history_item) to view each.

Comment: See answer by @dennis Golomazov, for an even better answer.

Answer (score 404):

Code for printing the entire history:

#### [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/readline.html)

One-liner (quick copy and paste):

```
import readline; print('\n'.join([str(readline.get_history_item(i + 1)) for i in range(readline.get_current_history_length())]))
```

(Or longer version...)

```
import readline
for i in range(readline.get_current_history_length()):
    print (readline.get_history_item(i + 1))
```

#### [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/readline.html)

One-liner (quick copy and paste):

```
import readline; print '\n'.join([str(readline.get_history_item(i + 1)) for i in range(readline.get_current_history_length())])
```

(Or longer version...)

```
import readline
for i in range(readline.get_current_history_length()):
    print readline.get_history_item(i + 1)
```

**Note**: `get_history_item()` is indexed from 1 to n.

Comment: One liner: `import readline; print '\n'.join([str(readline.get_history_item(i)) for i in range(readline.get_current_history_length())])`

Comment: This answer (and its non-example counterpart) exemplifies how important examples are to people. Thanks.

Comment: Cool! I've added an `history()` function with the above in my Python interpreter startup script (a script that's pointed to by env. var `$PYTHONSTARTUP`).  From now on, I can simply type `history()` in any interpreter session ;-)

Comment: Everytime I forget, how this is done, I come here for the answer, thank you Dennis.

Comment: I starred this who knows when and I'm back to snag this goodness one more time.  

Comment: 0 is my readline.get_current_history_length() despite having many lines in my history as accessed by up-arrow.  Nothing is displayed, consequently.  IPython 7.8.0

Comment: One liner for python3: `import readline; print('\n'.join([str(readline.get_history_item(i)) for i in range(readline.get_current_history_length())]))`

Answer (score 84):

With python 3 interpreter the history is written to
`~/.python_history`

Comment: I don't have this directory and I use Python 3.5.2

Comment: This would be for Unix-like OSes. I was able to retrieve my history on macOS with `cat ~/.python_history`

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I later found this covered in the docs here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/site.html#readline-configuration

Comment: Unfortunately, history doesn't seem to get updated when using virtual environments :-/

Comment: You need to `quit()` the interpreter for the current session history to be included in `~/.python_history`

Comment: while in the console, do: `%!cat ~/.python_history`

Comment: Remember all that any credentials you use within the python interpreter will be saved in this file.  At least, the file has 600 permissions.

Answer (score 22):

If you want to write the history to a file:

```
import readline
readline.write_history_file('python_history.txt')
```

The help function gives:

```
Help on built-in function write_history_file in module readline:

write_history_file(...)
    write_history_file([filename]) -> None
    Save a readline history file.
    The default filename is ~/.history.
```

Comment: will this persist across python sessions like ruby's pry history?

Comment: Maybe this answer was written before the readline function, but why not use readline.write_history_file ?   @lacostenycoder You can use readline to both read and write a history file that persists.

Comment: Very simple ! Though, on macos, it replaces each space character by the 4 characters sequence `\040`, which I turned back to space with `sed -e 's/\\040/ /g'` (or any replace command from within emacs or vi).

Comment: @duthen not only on macOS; this seems to be linked to [recent versions of readline](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17824899/735926).

Answer (score 16):

In IPython `%history -g` should give you the entire command history.

The default configuration also saves your history into a file named `.python_history` in your user directory.

Comment: For help run `%history?`. Nice tips there.

Comment: To save to a file run: `from datetime import datetime; file01="qtconsole_hist_"+datetime.today().strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')+".py";` and `%history -f $file01`

Comment: A file enables to see by lines, and not cells: `%hist -l 10 -n` # prints last 10 cells **VS**
`!tail -n 10 $file01` # prints last 10 lines

Comment: I wish this answer got more upvotes. Such an amazing feature! Especially that you can search by sessions. Thanks for sharing it.

Answer (score 5):

@Jason-V, it really help, thanks. then, i found [this](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/473900-history-and-completion-for-the-python-shell/) examples and composed to own snippet.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os, readline, atexit
python_history = os.path.join(os.environ['HOME'], '.python_history')
try:
  readline.read_history_file(python_history)
  readline.parse_and_bind("tab: complete")
  readline.set_history_length(5000)
  atexit.register(readline.write_history_file, python_history)
except IOError:
  pass
del os, python_history, readline, atexit
```

Comment: `Important!` This is only saving history **after** you exit from the REPL.

Comment: In addition, it need to be put into your `PYTHONSTARTUP` to work as expected. If you use *ironPython*, you don't need this.

Answer (score 5):

A simple function to get the history similar to unix/bash version.

Hope it helps some new folks.

```
def ipyhistory(lastn=None):
    """
    param: lastn Defaults to None i.e full history. If specified then returns lastn records from history.
           Also takes -ve sequence for first n history records.
    """
    import readline
    assert lastn is None or isinstance(lastn, int), "Only integers are allowed."
    hlen = readline.get_current_history_length()
    is_neg = lastn is not None and lastn < 0
    if not is_neg:
        flen = len(str(hlen)) if not lastn else len(str(lastn))
        for r in range(1,hlen+1) if not lastn else range(1, hlen+1)[-lastn:]:
            print(": ".join([str(r if not lastn else r + lastn - hlen ).rjust(flen), readline.get_history_item(r)]))
    else:
        flen = len(str(-hlen))
        for r in range(1, -lastn + 1):
            print(": ".join([str(r).rjust(flen), readline.get_history_item(r)]))
```

Snippet: Tested with Python3. Let me know if there are any glitches with python2.
Samples:

> Full History : `ipyhistory()`

> Last 10 History: `ipyhistory(10)`

> First 10 History: `ipyhistory(-10)`

**Hope it helps fellas.**

Comment: hi, thanks. I made your code snippet into a file xx.py. then after opening python, I did import xx. THen I tried ipyhistory() but it says, ">>> ipyhistory
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'ipyhistory' is not defined".  What's wrong?

Comment: I've [revised this to not print line numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62802740/1048186) since those usually get in the way for me, but I liked the line-limiting ability. (Even on Unix, I usually `cut -c 8` them out.)

Comment: If this is a simple function then I don’t want to see the complicated version.

Answer (score 4):

Since the above only works for python 2.x
for python 3.x (specifically 3.5) is similar but with a slight modification:

```
import readline
for i in range(readline.get_current_history_length()):
    print (readline.get_history_item(i + 1))
```

note the extra ()

(using shell scripts to parse .python_history or using python to modify the above code is a matter of personal taste and situation imho)

Comment: Win10 `C:\>python -m pip install readline` => `Collecting readline` \n `Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f4/01/2cf081af8d880b44939a5f1b446551a7f8d59eae414277fd0c303757ff1b/readline-6.2.4.1.tar.gz (2.3MB)` \n `|████████████████████████████████| 2.3MB 1.7MB/s` \n `ERROR: Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:` \n `ERROR: error: this module is not meant to work on Windows` \n `----------------------------------------` \n `ERROR: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\dblack\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-s6m4zkdw\readline\`

Comment: @bballdave025 Yes, you can't `pip install readline`, but [`readline` is installed by default on Windows.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62802667/print-python-history-from-interactive-prompt-on-windows)

Comment: Well, that makes things easier. Thanks @JosiahYoder

Comment: @bballdave025 I since learned that it isn't installed by default on windows, but if you follow the link, the instructions give details -- something like installing pyreadline or something.

Answer (score 1):

This should give you the commands printed out in separate lines:

```
import readline
map(lambda p:print(readline.get_history_item(p)),
    map(lambda p:p, range(readline.get_current_history_length()))
)
```

Comment: Can you please be more specific on formatting the code? Are you saying the parentheses are not matching?

Comment: I've fixed the formatting with some simple indentation. @AleksAndreev you may remove your downvote.

Answer (score 1):

Rehash of [Doogle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52575614/1048186)'s answer that doesn't printline numbers, but does allow specifying the number of lines to print.

```
def history(lastn=None):
    """
    param: lastn Defaults to None i.e full history. If specified then returns lastn records from history.
           Also takes -ve sequence for first n history records.
    """
    import readline
    assert lastn is None or isinstance(lastn, int), "Only integers are allowed."
    hlen = readline.get_current_history_length()
    is_neg = lastn is not None and lastn < 0
    if not is_neg:
        for r in range(1,hlen+1) if not lastn else range(1, hlen+1)[-lastn:]:
            print(readline.get_history_item(r))
    else:
        for r in range(1, -lastn + 1):
            print(readline.get_history_item(r))
```