# Why does readline.read_history_file give me 'IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory'

Tags: python, python-2.7, readline

My Python history file exists at ~/.pyhistory and contains the following:

```
from project.stuff import *
quit()
from project.stuff import *
my_thing = Thing.objects.get(id=21025)
my_thing
my_thing.child_set.all()
my_thing.current_state
my_thing.summary_set
my_thing.summary_set.all()
[ x.type for x in my_thing.child_set.all() ]
[ x.type for x in my_thing.child_set.all().order_by( 'datesubmitted' ) ]
quit()
```

I'm using virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper to build virtual environments. Today I'm having a problem with readline not reading in my history file:

```
>>> historyPath
'/Users/johndoe/.pyhistory'
>>> readline.read_history_file(historyPath)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

The file is readable and writable by me:

```
[johndoe@here]# ls -l ~/.pyhistory
-rw-------  1 johndoe  somegroup  325 21 Sep  2012 /Users/johndoe/.pyhistory
```

What could cause this problem?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Your history file appears to be an older version. Try converting it to the format expected by later versions of readline, most notably the first line should be literally '_HiStOrY_V2_' and all spaces should be replaced with '\040':

```
_HiStOrY_V2_
from\040project.stuff\040import\040*
quit()
from\040project.stuff\040import\040*
my_thing\040=\040Thing.objects.get(id=21025)
my_thing
my_thing.child_set.all()
my_thing.current_state
my_thing.summary_set
my_thing.summary_set.all()
[\040x.type\040for\040x\040in\040my_thing.child_set.all()\040]
[\040x.type\040for\040x\040in\040my_thing.child_set.all().order_by(\040'datesubmitted'\040)\040]
quit()
```

I am not sure whether this is a quirk of the underlying readline/libedit library or the Python readline module, but this is what worked for me.

Comment: Bumped into this after upgrading osx to Mavericks. The readline version must have been updated or something. Thanks.

Comment: I just ran into this. It's so annoying that the error is "No such file or directory", and that it's an IOError. It should be something like readline.FileParseError. And the message should be something like "Expected version 2 header in history file"

Comment: I just found out that this is an issue with GNU's readline vs BSD's libedit. I had a virtualenv whose readline was compiled against libedit. It's libedit that expects the funny header and \040 instead of spaces. The readline used by my system-wide homebrewed python was compiled against GNU's readline and it wrote the history file without the header and with regular spaces. I fixed the problem by deleting the virtualenv and re-creating it so that it would point at the same readline.so as the system python.

Comment: Did you, uh, just answer your own question in 2nd person..?

Comment: Yes, I believe E did! Perhaps ManicDee is a subscriber to a school of philosophy such as Idealism, monism/logoism, or presentism, and thus believes that the ManicDee of the past (the question asker) is an unrelated entity (after all, the ManicDee that answered the question is clearly a different entity: E has the answer, the other ManicDee did not). Though it also occurs to me that E might be a role-player, in this scenario playing the role of "Questioner" and "Answerer", two distinct characters in the single scene.