# Why am I getting Operation not permitted with Python's read_history_file?

Tags: python, readline

So. I own the file named ~/.osc_history, as shown below:

```
$ w
17:53  up  3:15, 5 users, load averages: 1.30 1.17 1.10
USER     TTY      FROM              LOGIN@  IDLE WHAT
kyma     console  -                14:39    3:14 -
kyma     s001     -                17:20       - w

$ ls -l ~/.osc_history 
-rw-r--r--  1 kyma  staff  13 Mar  6 17:41 /Users/kyma/.osc_history

$ ls -lO ~/.osc_history 
-rw-r--r--  1 kyma  staff  - 13 Mar  6 17:41 /Users/kyma/.osc_history
```

The header in the file is correct:

```
$ cat ~/.osc_history 
_HiStOrY_V2_
```

From the interactive prompt, the following code runs fine:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Jul 30 2016, 19:40:32) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.34)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os.path
>>> import readline
>>> histfile = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~"), ".osc_history")
>>> histfile
'/Users/kyma/.osc_history'
>>> readline.read_history_file(histfile)
>>> ^D
```

However, when I attempt to run the following, which I've called "yeuch.py"...

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import readline                 # Command line history
import os.path

histfile = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~"), ".osc_history")
if not os.path.isfile(histfile):     # If there's no history file...
    empty = open(histfile, "a")      # ... create an ALMOST empty one...
    empty.write("_HiStOrY_V2_\n")    # ... with the special header line
    empty.close()
readline.read_history_file(histfile) # Read history from previous sessions
readline.set_history_length(1000)    # Default length was -1 (infinite)
```

...I see:

```
$ python yeuch.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "yeuch.py", line 14, in <module>
    readline.read_history_file(histfile) # Read history from previous sessions
IOError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted
```

What the heck's going on? (I hope I'm not overlooking some stupid typo multiple times...)

Comment: (Nothing else is running or has .osc_history open, by the way. I've deleted and recreated it multiple times to see if there was anything wonky with that. But nay. It appears to be correct.)

Comment: @Posh_Pumpkin It's more than legal: I initially had another error message, which was solved by following the instructions at http://stackoverflow.com/a/17824899/447830

Comment: Can you write to another file with different filename?  If yes, it means that you do not have permissions to write to .osc_history

Comment: I have tried what you have on my machine and it works fine

Comment: If code works, it is most likely you have file access/ permission restrictions.

Comment: @oshaiken You saw that I could run it from the interactive prompt, yes? So, what causes the difference in permissions between interactive and non-interactive? (And, it does write to the file. If the file doesn't exist, it creates it and adds a line, as shown in the code above.) Filename change made no difference.

Comment: @smac89 It works okay on my Linux box as well. This seems to be something wonky with my Mac OS X. Are you running it under Mac OS X Sierra (10.12.3)?

Comment: I can duplicate this on OS X El Capitan, but I have to use `/usr/bin/python` (I have a brew installed `/usr/local/bin/python`). I can't diagnose the problem with `dtruss`, because OS X won't let me use it on restricted binaries.