# ipython: print complete history (not just current session)

Tags: ipython

in `ipython`, I can use `%hist` or `%history` to print recent history, but this only prints history from current session.

I would like to print all history, similar as bash `history`command does.

What I am trying to do is to get complete history, so that I can then search with regex, see what commands followed after specified commands, and so on

Speaking of history, can it also print timecodes?

**SIDE NOTE**:
In bash, I have written a simple script which prints history and I can grep it for keywords. I see times when certain commands were executed. I can specify `-A n` or `-B n`, where `n` is a number of lines `AFTER` or `BEFORE` a given command.
This is very handy, because I can easily find what I did when, and what followed, ...

I am looking for something similar for `ipython`

Comment: IPython saves its history in a history.sqlite file in `~/.ipython/profile_default/`. In there you'll find the tables: `sessions` (with timestamps), `history` and `output_history`.

Comment: @user3557327 - how can I access it from within `ipython` ?

Comment: I don't know if ipython shows an interface to it, but you can always access it directly with the [sqlite3 module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html).

Comment: Uhmm, ipython crashes at exit when I open the database directly in it, so it might not be the best idea to open it from ipython itself.

Comment: `%history -g` will show you all of it. `-g` searches the history, and if you give it no pattern, you get everything.

Comment: @Thomas K - thanks, `%history -g` works. The only think I am missing is having timecodes with the commands, rather than `session/line`. I tend to remember that I did operation `X` on Tuesday morning, but I have no idea what `session` that was. Therefore, I would find it really helpful if I could print timecodes with history. I guess this is not supported, correct ?

Comment: Not directly. IPython stores timestamps for the start and end of each session, but not for each individual command. You could write a tool around the [HistoryAccessor](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/api/generated/IPython.core.history.html#IPython.core.history.HistoryAccessor) API to display it in a different format.

Comment: `%history -g -f filename` to save it to file.

Comment: @Liso that should be the answer to this question. :)

Comment: @ThomasK, it would be very helpful to have a date/time stamp on the history commands. It may increase the size of the history database (`sqlite?`) slightly, but probably wont complicate things too much. I posted this intermittent error on github before (https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/11004). Now I am trying to figure out what series of steps led me there. Because I am using `zsh`, and other tools along with `ipython`, these tools may be interacting with each other, and I wanted to check what were the series of commands which lead to the `.pyc` files being generated.

Comment: However, because I don’t have any time stamps on the `ipython` history, I can’t correlate the other commands, I ran on `zsh`.

Comment: history -g -f some-file.txt do the work

Answer (score 243):

In `ipython` enter:

```
%history -g
```

It does not print time codes but it does print session/line number.

Answer (score 43):

First use `%hist -o -g -f ipython_history.md` to output the history (input and output) to a text file. (http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-history)

Then you can use the the `get_session_info` function to retreive the date and time for the session you are interested in.(http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.core.history.html?highlight=hist#IPython.core.history.HistoryAccessor.get_session_info)

```
profile_hist=IPython.core.history.HistoryAccessor(profile='default')
profile_hist.get_session_info(100)
```

This will print out something like

```
(100, datetime.datetime(2018, 2, 13, 19, 8, 30, 40691), None, None, '')
```

This means that the session 100 started on the 13th of Feb 2018 19:08:30.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the Firefox extension that [@larssend](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5136067/larssend) found: [SQLite Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager-webext/)

It has a GUI for opening a database file and issuing various sqlite commands from a menu. You get the added bonus of seeing the SQL commands that generated the output. Here's mine for my ipython `%history` in `~/.ipython/profile_default/history.sqlite`:

[image]

And it even has a menu for generating plots (scatter, line, bar, etc) from your data!