# How to get output history in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipython

Is there any way to obtain a Jupyter notebook's entire output history?

Answer (score 0):

There are two objects in python In and Out objects.
That's how they work:
First wrote some code

```
import math
math.sin(2) #now, replacing with math.cos(3) and running again
```

It's Output:

```
0.9092974268256817 #when replaced with cos, O/P: -0.4161468365471424
```

Now to check input history:

```
In [4]: print(In)
['', 'import math', 'math.sin(2)', 'math.cos(2)', 'print(In)']
```

Now to check output history:

```
In [5]: Out
Out[5]: {2: 0.9092974268256817, 3: -0.4161468365471424}
```

Note: this will not get history when the notebook is closed and freshly started. It will work in the current session only.

Check this link for more explanation: https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/01.04-input-output-history.html

Answer (score 0):

For example, you do something like this - `In[1]: 1+2` you get `Out[1]: 3`.

So, you can do this in the next line :

```
In[2]: print(In[1])
```

And also for output

`print(Out[1])`

Check this - [Output History](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/01.04-input-output-history.html)

Answer (score 0):

This might help (similar question, but broader) because it asks for the whole history, not only in the current session, but previous sessions as well. Answers are great. [ipython: print complete history (not just current session)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25124037)