# Invoking history command on terminal via Python script

Tags: python

I am running a python script which is using subprocess to execute "history" command on my Ubuntu terminal.  Apparently,I am getting this error

```
history: not found
```

I got to know that **history** can not be invoked by any script by default.
What can I do to overcome this? Or any other possible alternatives.

readline.get_history_item() method isnt working either.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how do you see the entire command history in interactive python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6558765/how-do-you-see-the-entire-command-history-in-interactive-python)

Comment: @oystein-hr : It is not working out for me, thats why I asked it again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT


e = Popen("bash -i -c  'history -r;history' ", shell=True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
output = e.communicate()
```

Comment: May I suggest: `subprocess.check_output(['bash', '-i', '-c', 'history -r; history'])`?