# How to view the entire history of Python commands in the Mac terminal

Tags: python, macos, terminal

Is there a way to view the entire command history of Python, from the point of the first command 'python' after the installation, in the Mac terminal?

**UPDATE:** So, it is not possible to retrieve command history from python in the mac terminal. The best solution was proposed by BobStein-VisiBone in [how do you see the entire command history in interactive python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6558765/how-do-you-see-the-entire-command-history-in-interactive-python) where he mentions using iPython. Unfortunately, even that won't help retrieve the history of the commands that were input in the terminal before setting up iPython. In other words, those commands are probably gone for good.

Comment: which command do you want?

Comment: When you run "python" and get the python prompt, you are now inside the python interpreter program.  If that is what you mean, go here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6558765/how-do-you-see-the-entire-command-history-in-interactive-python

Comment: Or here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6558765/how-do-you-see-the-entire-command-history-in-interactive-python

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
history | grep "^[^a-zA-Z]*python *"
```

This will print out your terminal history of all commands that start with `python`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Davis. Unfortunately, this prints only the "python" commands. The question was actually about all the commands run in python on the Mac terminal. I will update my question.