# How to get history from Python C API

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, embed, python-c-api

I want to get history count (and contents) from Python.

From command line it's possible with `readline` module (installed via `pip install pyreadline`):

```
import readline
x=readline.get_current_history_length()
x
```

Yields 2, as it should. 
However the same code using Python C API always returns zero, regardless of actual history:

```
#include <Python.h>

long GetHistoryCount() {
    Py_Initialize();
    PyRun_SimpleString("import readline");
    PyRun_SimpleString("x=readline.get_current_history_length()");

    PyObject *mainModule = PyImport_AddModule("__main__");
    PyObject *var = PyObject_GetAttrString(mainModule, "x");

    Py_Finalize();
    return PyLong_AsLong(var);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    long count = GetHistoryCount();
    printf("Count: %ld", count);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Prints: `Count: 0`

How can I get history from Python C API?

Found readline module in [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6558765/how-do-you-see-the-entire-command-history-in-interactive-python)

Comment: Hm, how should the history count be anything else than 0? Is there a history file which is read on startup automatically? With the C readline API a history file is _not_ read automatically, but only on specific request (`read_history()`)

Comment: It's Python interpreter history, not OS history. For normal Python invocation (via Python interpreter) it works without specifying files.

Comment: Yes, of course, but you do not invoke a python interpreter here. So, where should history entries come from?

Comment: I thought python context executed lines somewhere.

Comment: I think, your main misunderstanding here is, that `PyRun_SimpleString()` does _not_ use the readline interface, but passes the command directly to the interpreter. So the commands executed with this function will not be inserted into the readline history.

Comment: You could, however, add each command to the readline history manually by invoking `readline.add_history("some command")` for each command. But you have to be cautios to properly escape the command first.

Comment: Thank you! Maybe there's a way to add interpreter callback for that, or some setting?