# How to get executed commands history on python 3.7 shell prompt as same as RHEL

Tags: python-3.x

I want to know that how to get executed commands/codes history in python3.x as we are getting by history command in RHEL-8??

Tried history command and print(history) on >>>(python 3.x shell) prompt but getting error.

```
Python 3.7.4 (tags/v3.7.4:e09359112e, Jul  8 2019, 20:34:20) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> history
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    history
NameError: name 'history' is not defined
>>> 
>>> print(history)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    print(history)
NameError: name 'history' is not defined
>>>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how do you see the entire command history in interactive python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6558765/how-do-you-see-the-entire-command-history-in-interactive-python)

Comment: Getting below error:-       Python 3.7.4 (tags/v3.7.4:e09359112e, Jul  8 2019, 20:34:20) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> readline.get_current_history_length()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    readline.get_current_history_length()
NameError: name 'readline' is not defined
>>>

Comment: `pip install readline` (or `pip install pyreadline` if you're on Windows).