# Where is the Python interpreter startup script for putting a history function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to add a function like this:

```
def history():
  import readline
  for i in range(readline.get_current_history_length()):
    print (readline.get_history_item(i + 1))
```

so that whenever I'm in a Python shell (like running `python3`) or if I hit a breakpoint using ipdb in Python code, that I can just call `history()`.

Where do I add this code? (MacOS)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how do you see the entire command history in interactive python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6558765/how-do-you-see-the-entire-command-history-in-interactive-python)

Comment: I have the function already, but I'm trying to figure out where I can add this code so that I don't have to write the function everytime

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to achive that using the PYTHONSTARTUP env var.
Create a script that contains this code, and export the variable to your shell's profile

https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONSTARTUP

Comment: I'm not sure what's the issue, but when I run `cat $PYTHONSTARTUP`, the command just hangs without printing anything

Comment: @Michael you mean echo $PYTHONSTARTUP?

Comment: echo doesn't print anything

Comment: That means that its empty, create a python file with the code you want, and then add `export PYTHONSTARTUP='path_to_your_file'` to your shell config