# How to get interpreter commands history in python

Tags: python, shell, interpreter

I inserted couple commands in python interpreter and want to see whole history after re-enter in interpreter shell.
How caan I do it?

For example:

```
$ python
Python 3.7.1 (default, Jul 14 2021, 18:08:28) 
[Clang 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.29)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print('hello')
>>> print('world')
>>> exit()
```

And after re-enter insert something like `history` and be able to see inserted below commands

```
$ python
Python 3.7.1 (default, Jul 14 2021, 18:08:28) 
[Clang 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.29)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> {some_history_like_command}
print('hello')
print('world')
exit()
>>>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you see the entire command history in interactive Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6558765/how-do-you-see-the-entire-command-history-in-interactive-python)

Comment: @Arvind Thanks. I really tried to search same question but didn't find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add `~/.python_profile` file:

```py
def myhistory(condition=None):
  import readline as r
  if type(condition) == int:
    max_length = r.get_current_history_length()
    if max_length <= condition:
      length = [max_length]
    else:
      length = [(max_length-condition), max_length]
    for cmd in [str(r.get_history_item(i+1)) for i in range(*length)]:
      print(cmd)
  else:
    for cmd in [str(r.get_history_item(i+1)) for i in range(r.get_current_history_length())]:
      if condition is None:
        print(cmd)
      else:
        if condition in cmd:
          print(cmd)
```

2. Add `export PYTHONSTARTUP="$HOME/.python_profile"` line into `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile`
3. Run python shell and insert `myhistory(n: int)` or `myhistory(s: str)`

   - `myhistory(n: int)` will show last used `n`th commands (or `n` lines for multiline commands)
   - `myhistory(s: str)` will show all commands with `s` substring

```py
>>> myhistory(3)
print('world')
exit()
myhistory(3)
>>> myhistory('print')
print('hello')
print('world')
myhistory('print')
>>>
```

※ `myhistory(s: str)` will print only one line with `s` inclusion even if original command is multiline:

```
>>> for i in range(1,2):
...   print(i)
... 
>>> myhistory('print')
  print(i)
myhistory('print')
>>>
```

PS also python history is stored inside `~/.python_history` file and may be read by standard bash text readers