# Getting pyreadline3.Readline's history working with Python 3.9

Tags: python, read-eval-print-loop, command-history

I am following [this
Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7008316/2153235)'s procedure for
accessing Python's REPL command history -- specifically at the Conda
prompt, not in an IDE.

I am using Python 3.9 installed under Anaconda on Windows 10.  Version
3.9 needed for backward compatibility with colleagues' past work.

The history is apparently handled by `pyreadline3.Readline`, which is
the implementation of Gnu's *readline* for Python 3.  I am relying on
Anaconda to manage the package depedencies.  Unfortunately, the REPL
commands aren't being captured.

Annex A shows a session transcript in the Conda environment `py39`,
which contains Python 3.9.  It contains three chunks:

1. Installation of pyreadline3
2. Test-driving the history capture in Python, which fails
3. Using Cygwin's Bash to confirm that the written history file is
   empty.

***What else can I do to enable history capture?***

**Tangentially relevant:** `%USERPROFILE%\.python_history` captures REPL commands, but does not update until one exits the Python REPL session.

## Annex A: Session transcript

```
REM Insteall pyreadline3
REM --------------------
(py39) C:\Users\User.Name> conda install pyreadline3
<...snip...>
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): \ DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): repo.anaconda.com:443
<...snip...>
done
Solving environment: done
==> WARNING: A newer version of conda exists. <==
  current version: 23.7.2
  latest version: 23.7.3
Please update conda by running
    $ conda update -n base -c defaults conda
Or to minimize the number of packages updated during conda update use
     conda install conda=23.7.3
## Package Plan ##
  environment location: C:\Users\User.Name\anaconda3\envs\py39
  added / updated specs:
    - pyreadline3
The following packages will be downloaded:
    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    pyreadline3-3.4.1          |   py39haa95532_0         148 KB
    ------------------------------------------------------------
The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:
  pyreadline3        pkgs/main/win-64::pyreadline3-3.4.1-py39haa95532_0
Proceed ([y]/n)? y <RETURN>
Downloading and Extracting Packages
pyreadline3-3.4.1    | 148 KB    |                                                                              |   0% DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): repo.anaconda.com:443
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://repo.anaconda.com:443 "GET /pkgs/main/win-64/pyreadline3-3.4.1-py39haa95532_0.conda HTTP/1.1" 200 151256
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done

REM Illustrate in Python that commands aren't capture
REM -------------------------------------------------
(py39) C:\Users\User.Name> python
Python 3.9.17 (main, Jul  5 2023, 21:22:06) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from pyreadline3 import Readline
>>> readline = Readline()
>>> readline.get_current_history_length() # Commands captured
0
>>> readline.get_history_length() # Length of buffer
100
>>> import os # Write history to file
>>> os.getcwd()
   'C:\\Users\\User.Name'
>>> readline.write_history_file("./pyHistory.txt")

# Use Cygwin's Bash to show that target history file is empty
#------------------------------------------------------------
User.Name@Laptop-Name /c/Users/User.Name
$ new #  This is "ls -ltA", cleaned up with "sed"
              0 2023-08-30 13:10 pyHistory.txt*
        2359296 2023-08-29 01:39 NTUSER.DAT*
        <...snip...>
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading the documentation from on the built-in [readline](https://docs.python.org/3/library/readline.html#module-readline), and also about the how [pyreadline3](https://github.com/pyreadline3/pyreadline3/blob/master/pyreadline3/lineeditor/history.py#L35) has implemented history, we can summarize the situation as follows.

The default files for python history are stored in the following files (under `$HOME`).

```bash
.history            # Default pyreadline / pyreadline3
.python_history     # Default readline (built-in) when interactive
```

Furthermore it states that if you want to use the `.history` file, it has to already exist!

The example code from above link, shows that you can load/save the file at any time.

> "*The following example achieves the same goal but supports concurrent interactive sessions, by only appending the new history.*"

```py
import atexit
import os
import readline
histfile = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~"), ".python_history")

try:
    readline.read_history_file(histfile)
    h_len = readline.get_current_history_length()
except FileNotFoundError:
    open(histfile, 'wb').close()
    h_len = 0

def save(prev_h_len, histfile):
    new_h_len = readline.get_current_history_length()
    readline.set_history_length(1000)
    readline.append_history_file(new_h_len - prev_h_len, histfile)
atexit.register(save, h_len, histfile)
```

This can be further manipulated in the `rlcompleter` [config](https://docs.python.org/3/library/site.html#rlcompleter-config).

---

**Note**:
There is an unmerged [PR](https://github.com/pyreadline3/pyreadline3/pull/9) in the original pyreadline3 repo. That PR fixes tab and ANSI color usage. It is therefore suggested to use the clone from [here](https://github.com/eabase/pyreadline3/tree/master) instead.  In addition, it would make more sense that both readline implementations use the same file, preferably `.python_history`...